# Creating a cumulative factor based on multiple buffers

Tags: qgis, buffer

I'm using QGIS 2.12.0 and am trying to formulate a hierarchy for the risk factor associated with footpath polygons based on their proximity to pedestrian generators and the importance factor of that generator. For example, a bus stop will have a buffer radius of 100m and a factor of 10, while a small park will have a radius of 400m and a factor of 5. When the buffers are created, it's obviously going to create several hundred overlapping buffers and I wanted each intersecting segment to inherit a cumulative factor based on the overlapping factors (I've tried to illustrate what I mean in the pic).
Heat maps using the factor work ok, but they don't take the radius into account.[image]

Does anyone have any ideas how I might go about achieving this?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would go about getting the cumulative buffer values but you could try doing a raster weighted overlay [analysis](http://grindgis.com/software/qgis/raster-overlay-analysis-qgis). You could try to make different rasters for your factors (converting the buffer polygons to raster) and overlay them ( this is what I've seen people do normally )

Comment: To get the sum of the buffers you can try `Join attributes by location` in Data Management in the Vector Menu ( it will result in a new shapefile but it does give the option of `sum` ) I'm not sure if this will work or not.

Comment: Is it possible for buffers having same radius and factor to overlap? And should in this case factors sum up? As result do you need polygons or a raster?

Comment: Hasan, the Join attributes by Location was not successful - in fact, it crashed everytime I tried to run it - perhaps because of the number of buffers involved. Detlev, I do want the buffers with the same radius and factor to overlap and sum - as for the final result, I'm not fussed if it's a polygon or a raster. I appreciate the help!